# Error inserting Currency characters in sqlite database from eclipse / android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm inserting queries like below in sqlite database from sql file via eclipse:

```
INSERT INTO "Country_Table" 
("countryid", "country_name" , "language", "currency", "VAT_abbr", "VAT_rate", "VAT_label", "creation_date" , "update_date", "status")
VALUES
("3","Austria","German","€","USt.","20,00","UID-Nr.","2013/06/27","2013/06/27","1");
```

**Execution is as below:**
07-19 16:46:43.739: I/System.out(23733): ---------------------executing----------------INSERT INTO "Country_Table" ("countryid", "country_name" , "language", "currency", "VAT_abbr", "VAT_rate", "VAT_label", "creation_date" , "update_date", "status") VALUES ("3","Austria","German","�","USt.","20,00","UID-Nr.","2013/06/27","2013/06/27","1");

This sql file is placed in assets folder.
But executing this queries, I found problem with the symbols `"€"` & `"£"`, but it works fine with `"$"`.

Insertion of the symbols takes place with `'?'` symbol whenever executed.

**EDIT**

I'm executing this query in SQLite then it works properly, but when executing this for android local database, the symbols of EURO and POUND are inserted as '?' in the database.

Comment: Show us a creation code for the table

Comment: Why have you tagged it in android? Does that have anything to do with android?

Comment: Hello I think you should look at escaping qutes with double qutes '' in SQLite

Comment: @MarekSebera Datatype for the currency field is varchar.

Comment: Getting solved this error by using WINDOWS-1252 as encoding instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the SQL file is encoded as UTF-8, and that your code that reads the file (which you have not shown) does not change the encoding.

Comment: Getting solved this error by using WINDOWS-1252 instead of UTF-8 as encoding.